# run PHP and Nodejs app together in a cPanel account

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, cpanel, nuxt.js

I have installed Nodejs on my cPanel Cloudlinux server.

I created a Nodejs app (`Nuxt.js`) for my website frotend via `Software > Setup Node.js App` in my cPanel account and linked it to my website root (`example.com/`)
Now I want to create an API PHP service (`Laravel`) for my website backend and place it in my `example.com/api` directory which it returns JSON from this address. But when I visit this url, it returns my Nodejs app page which I created before for website root.

In fact, I want the `publci_html/api` folder to be exclude from rendering via Nodejs server.

Is it possible?
Or should I commit some changes in `.htaccess` file?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create `api.domain.com` as a subdomain so you can use api.domain.com (public_html/api) for the Laravel application without any problem.

But if you have .httacess in the root directory and Node.js use rewrite rules, you can also add RewriteRule code to excluding :

```
RewriteRule ^(api)($|/) - [L]
```

Comment: I created a subdomain and added this line of code into my .htaccess file in public_html root. But nothing happened and the problem exists.

Comment: @FredII If you add subdomain no need to change root .htacess just use the subdomain. when you open api.domain.com what you see?

Comment: When I visit that url, I see the exact content which is "It's works!" that written in /home/mydomain/app/app.js which is the Nodejs app. Note that I defined my root domain (`domain.com/`) as `Application URL` in Nodejs app settings in cPanel.